# How to differentiate elements with the same class but unique aria-labelledby attribute

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, watir-webdriver

As part of a Watir-Webdriver test script, I'm attempting to click a button in a jQuery UI modal dialog window that pops up.

The modal dialog pops up (I can see it in the browser). However, when checking if the div is present by using `:class`, it returns `false`.

I think the issue is that there are 4 divs with the same class, with the first three having `display:none`. So, I tried:

```
   @browser.elements(:css => '.duplicate_class')[3].present?
```

to see if I could select the forth `div`. That returned a `Net::ReadTimeout` error.

There isn't an id attribute, but there is a unique aria-labelledby value for each div. I'm not entirely sure how to use `:aria-labelledby` as an attribute (not sure if this would work anyway).

Unfortunately, I can't provide any code. I know this will hinder any assistance so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the aria-labelledby attribute is unique, I would try using that:

```
@browser.div(:aria_labelledby => 'the_attribute_value').present?
```

Note that when the aria attributes are used in the locator, the dashes need to be replaced by underscores.

Comment: Using the above example, the following error is returned `'<main>': undefined local variable or method 'labelledby' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: Based on the exception, you have typed the locator incorrectly. You have likely typed `:aria-labelledby` instead of `:aria_labelledby`. Note the difference between the underscore and dash.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten to delete my incorrect attempt further up in my script. Changing the dash to an underscore worked. I'm now able to locate the required element